# Confused between a copy constructor and a converting constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++03

Since I have doubts about this question (for C++03) I am posting it here.I just read about conversion constructors and it states that

> "To be a converting constructor, constructor must have single
>   argument and be declared without keyword explicit."

Now my question is whether the copy constructor can be called a conversion constructor provided it is not explicitly declared ? Does it qualify to be one ?
I believe it cant be called a conversion constructor because it only accepts the same type parameter ths resulting in no conversion. For Instance

```
foo a;
foo b;
a = 100; //a Conversion constructor would be called (i.e) foo(int a){...}
a = b ;  //Since both objects are same type and have been initialized the assignment operator will be called (if there is an overloaded version otherwise the default will be called)
```

Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: `operator=()` will be preferred if possible, but the real question is "what happens when a suitable `operator=()` implementation can't be found?"

Comment: foo a = 100; // is conversion construction
foo b = a; // is copy construction

Comment: [class.conv.ctor]/3 "A non-explicit copy-constructor (12.8) is a converting constructor. An implicitly-declared copy constructor
is not an explicit constructor; it may be called for implicit type conversions."

Comment: It's just a name. They are all constructors at the end of the day.

Comment: Note a copy-ctor can also be called with an object of a derived class.

Comment: @NeilKirk And at the end of the day, methods are just functions with a hidden argument, functions are just sequences of instructions... so why bother trying to give meaningful names to concepts, right?

Comment: @DyP If you have the answer, post it as an answer..

Comment: @DyP in fact, you're calling it with a reference to the base-type even when you're passing an object of derived class. It's not the same reference.

Comment: @sehe Yes, I wanted to point out this "slicing" (inside the copy-ctor, the reference doesn't do slicing) is a conversion.

Comment: @Dyp I wouldn't say that counts as a conversion. It's a 'partial interpretation' more than a 're-interpretation' in a way :)

Comment: @sehe I wanted to include [an example using virtual functions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4cc161d13b7430163bf89c1a5faf29ba-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336) where the behaviour is different depending on the type of the argument of the copy-ctor, but I think it'd be too off-topic (as the conversion involves binding to a reference).

Comment: @DyP we don't need no bleeding conversions, copies or constructors to get confused: [it's virtual, all access is via (polymorphic) references, the `Derived::foo` just calls `Base::foo()` and there's no slicing in sight!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f53dbc2bce5580efbcdb35e41217ccbc-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336)

Answer (score 10):

Quoting the Standard:

[class.conv.ctor]/3

> **A non-explicit copy-constructor (12.8) is a converting constructor**. An implicitly-declared copy constructor is not an explicit constructor; it may be called for implicit type conversions.

So yes, a copy-ctor is a converting ctor.

Also note [conv]/1 which specifies and points out in a remark:

> Note: a standard conversion sequence can be empty, i.e., it can consist of no conversions.

and in /3:

> An expression `e` can be implicitly converted to a type `T` if and only if the declaration `T t=e;` is well-formed

So the set of implicit conversions contain the empty conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a copy constructor  is what it is -- a copy constructor.  Which isn't a conversion constructor that *converts* from one type to a different type.

Comment: Should this be a comment? And can you fix the grammar?

Comment: Except that what it is *is* a converting constructor. The conversion to the same type may be trivial, but it's still technically a conversion.